# Deleting Blank Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following macro which has worked great for copy and paste, then the person working with the workbook goes to the newly created sheet and starts deleting rows not necessary to the end product.  I have tried adding a line to have the macro delete blank rows, but it is not working.  I think possibly because it is not on the active sheet?  If I could get the macro to delete blank rows in the range I have added to the macro then I can build from there; as we have many ranges to look through and delete from.  I am still learning about macros so any education you could give me would be much appreciated.

Here is the macro I have.  It is the 'Delete lines from new sheet that is not working.

```
Sub CopyandPaste()

'Copy and Paste to Worksheets
'

'Select from MASTER sheet
    Range("A1:H1500").Select
    Selection.Copy
' Add new sheet for each Tech
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Paste
'Copy again to paste values
    Range("A1:H1500").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'Name new sheet Tech's name
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Sheets(Sheets.Count).Range("a2").Value
'Delete blank lines from new sheet
    ActiveSheet.Range("F282:F834").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In most case runtime exception are caused by the Select and ActiveSheet methods.

You need to use them less as possible and use Range and Worksheet variables instead :

```
Sub CopyandPaste()

    'Copy and Paste to Worksheets
    '

    'Select from MASTER sheet
     Dim MasterSheet As Worksheet
     Set MasterSheet = Sheets("Master")

     MasterSheet.Range("A1:H1500").Copy


     Dim newSheet As Worksheet
     ' Add new sheet for each Tech
     Set newSheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
     newSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone _
         , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
     newSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False

    'Copy again to paste values

     Application.CutCopyMode = False
   'Name new sheet Tech's name
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets.Item(newSheet.Range("a2").Value).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    newSheet.Name = newSheet.Range("a2").Value

    'Delete blank lines from new sheet
        For i = 834 To 282 Step -1
        With newSheet.Cells(i, "F")
            If .Text = "" Then .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the newSheet. line and it still gave me a run time error "424"  Object required.  So it looks like I am still missing something.  Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: I tried my code in a blank workbook with random values and everything work fine.  Where have you pasted the code ? in a distihct module or directly in the sheet Code ?

Comment: It is in a module in the workbook.  Should I have it somewhere else?

Comment: I have copied this macro into my workbook and added paste formats.  It copies and paste beautifully and I get no run time error, but the range is totally blank and still there.

Comment: Only rows between 282 and 834 having a blank "F" column will be deleted.  Is that what you want ?

Comment: Yes for now. The sheet I am creating and using to test has nothing in that range and it should delete and move information up, but that is not happening.  I just try breaking the line in 2 with select then selection doing the delete.  It selected the cells but did not delete the rows.

Comment: I just noticed that it is deleting 3 rows that are blank to begin with, but the rows that had formulas in them will not delete even though they do not show formulas after pastevalues.  Suggestion on ways to get around this?

Comment: I found a macro that is deleting lines, just not the lines I need deleted.  Maybe you can help me on that.  After trying this macro included in my copy paste I realize that if I can get this on to look at column A and F and if anything in either leave it working for rows 1 to 834 this would work for me.  But I know it is not wrote to do that yet.

Comment: Delete blank lines from new sheet
     newSheet.Range("F282:F834").Select
    Dim i, LastRow
        LastRow = Range("f282").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If cells(i, "a").Value = "" Then
        cells(i, "f").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        Next

Comment: Hi @user3554998, I think you should start a new question for that point. (you can send me the link here).  Consider marking an answer as accepted if your problem is solved too ;)  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The routine below is how I might tackle this task. Comments are included to help explain what's going on:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyAndPasteRev2()

Dim Source As Range, Dest As Range, Remove As Range
Dim Master As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet

'set references up-front, assuming you
'start with the MASTER sheet active
Set Master = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Source = Master.Range("A1:H1500")
Set Target = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
Set Dest = Target.Range("A1")

'copy range from master to target
Source.Copy Destination:=Dest

'copy the column width formatting from master to target
Source.Copy
Dest.PasteSpecial (xlPasteColumnWidths)

'remove rows that are blank in col F using
'autofilter to look for empty cells
Dest.AutoFilter
With Target.AutoFilter.Range
    .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=vbNullString
    Set Remove = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Remove.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End With

'clear filters safely
With Target
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    If .FilterMode = True Then
        .ShowAllData
    End If
End With

'move target sheet to be the last one in the workbook
Target.Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

End Sub
```

Comment: I see that with Field:=6 you are having it look at column F for blanks, but there are rows that are blank in that column that I do not want deleted. Can you set a range with this?

Comment: Yes, you can adjust the `Remove` `Range` object as you see fit by using `.Offset` and `.Resize`

Comment: Is the range containing blanks you'd like to remove between F282 and F834? Will this ever potentially change (as your master table changes, for example)?

Comment: It is just one of a number of ranges.  Each range has a title line that does not have anything in column F, but do not want deleted else the whole range for that title is deleted.  Example the title in A281 is Overrides and there can be entries anywhere in the F282 through F834, which is full of formulas.

Comment: OK. Can you programmatically determine these ranges based on the master table? More info on that would be extremely useful (and should probably be added to your original question)

Comment: I will try to explain the project to you. This is a workbook with 3-4 sheets that populate a MASTER sheet based on a dropdown box in A2. I have buttons that give totals based on state, copy and paste to new sheet, create summary sheet, and e-mail sheets.  The MASTER sheet is populated by formulas and right now when we copy and paste we go to new sheet and delete all blank and unnecessary lines and I want to do that by macro if possible.  Either on it own button or with copy and paste.

Comment: OK, so considering what you wrote above, you want to look through the full range and if a cell is empty in column F AND empty in column A you want to delete the entire row -- right?